# TeeChart in ReportBuilder ignores prouping

Tags: teechart

I am using TeeChart within a ReportBuilder Report and am now facing a problem:
Lets say I have a Report with a DataPipeline containing a table with two columns.
Now I grouped by one of the columns and put a TeeChart into the group content.
The ReportBuilder is now creating the groups as espected - however, the TeeCart within
the group content always uses all data from the pipeline (nongrouped) non the less - resulting
in repeating the very same (heavily overloaded) TeeChart within each group.

What is the best current practice here?
Is there a way to make the TeeChart to "respect" the grouping or do I have to create a Subreport in each group?

Many thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Digital Metaphors](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/) are who develop, support and maintain the integration of TeeChart into Report Builder. I don't know if they support some kind of connection for the data in the report and the chart.

I'd suggest you to take a look at the `TDBCrossTabSource` in TeeChart. As you can see in the *[Summary grouping data](http://wiki.teechart.net/index.php?title=VCLTutorial8#Summary_grouping_data)* section in the *Tutorial 8 - Database access*, `TDBCrossTabSource` supports grouping data by a field.